# Examples of known or fallow existential symbioses between different scientific disciplines (in an essential, not merely engineering, sense)

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, identity

The film [“The Proud Rebel”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymov6V5JWu0) plays in the time after the American Civil War, featuring a father (John Chandler) who travels with his son David (that is also in real life actor Alan Ladd's son) who is mute, because of shock°) in the war – mother died in the burning house. This father takes a stand for his mute son, also relating to how he could be recovered from his muteness.

Acting in this sense, Chandler was embroiled into a concatenation of incidents that lead to a fighting to the dead. Caused by these dramatic events, suddenly the son begins to speak because he may save the life of the father, by calling him to look out for a danger from behind.°°)

Do examples exist that two sciences, which bear a relation to each other, have similar symbioses, as exist between the father and the son in this film? The question is especially interesting since perhaps there are even hidden, hitherto unnoticed possibilities of coherences between the individual sciences that have been ignored because people thought they were weeds.

One science A would then show the other science B its true aim, and hence save its hitherto forgotten identity (= life), if the science B would at the same time assist science A to gain access to its language (in a wider sense, again a picture for identity, self-consciousness, aim). Additionally the question raises whether it is possible that a kind of father-son relationship may exist between different sciences.

---

**Footnotes:**

°) 6:00 – 6:10 min. in the film.
°°) 39:20 – 39:52 min. in the film.

Comment: Neither corporations nor sciences are people (despite the US Supreme Court), they do not have true aims, forgotten identities or self-consciousness. As for father-son, one could say that some sciences "begot" others, say computer science split off from mathematics in 1960-s. But I am afraid that if this question can be answered at all it is only subjectively and reasoning by loose association that it itself uses.

Comment: @Conifold: But, the scientific community, manifest as its sub-folks in physics, chemistry etc., are like peoples who all have kinds of national geniuses. Perhaps these geniuses have lost their natural identities, for instance by long-lasting religious influences or by propaganda. − By the way physics is the son (who cannot speak), and chemistry is the father who should make, in his own interest, an effort to deliver the syntax  (additionally, the question is interesting, who _really_ caused the American Civil War that lead to the son's articulation blockade).